# send list<xmldocument> to wcf, how to do it?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I'm trying to send List to wcf.
i want to send it as json, is there a way ?

when I'm trying to serialize, i get empty string, why ?

```
public string ImportXml(List<XmlDocument> docs,string token)
        {
            Account user =  GetCurrentUser(token);
            string url = string.Format("{0}ImportXml/{1}", ServiceUrl, user.Unumber);
            string contentType = "text/json";
            x.Serialize(Console.Out, docs);
            string jsonReq = _serializer.Serialize(docs);
            bool response = false;
            HttpRequestHandler handler = new HttpRequestHandler();
            string result = handler.HttpPostWithToken(url, jsonReq, contentType, token);
            return result ; 
        }
```

Comment: Does the docs list have anything in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnally i got list of strings with xml in it.

it is much better, because that way we can work with anyone, and not only C#.

and i moved to newtonsoft instead JSS.

```
List<string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the collection docs before sending into WCF is must be serialized into the JSON for example in this way:

```
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

where doc is XmlDocument.

Or for Javascript in this way: [Converting between XML and JSON](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/)

After you get collection of XmlDocument into WCF method try convert each element of entrance collection:

```
var documents = new  List<XmlDocument>();

foreach (var doc in docs)
{
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(doc);
  documents.Add(xmlDoc);
}
```